# Notation used for equations in finite fields

Tags: number-theory, notation, finite-fields

In some work I am currently writing there is a point at which I have to put values into a few different formulae. I am operating over a finite field so I aim to use values in this field.

As an example of this over the field $\mathbb{F}_{17}$,
$$
m=x_1+x_2+x_3=5+7+11=23=6
$$

My concern relates to the use of equality. Is my current use of notation appropriate, or would I be better off using congruence?

This alternative would lead to 
$$
m \equiv x_1+x_2+x_3 \equiv 5+7+11 \equiv 23 \equiv 6 \pmod{17}
$$

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as it is crystal clear you're doing arithmetic modulo $\;17\;$, I think equality is way easier, shorter and clearer.

Comment: If it is clear from the context you're computing in the finite field, I would simply write $5+7+11=6$.

Comment: OK, thanks to you both

Comment: Finite fields go beyond basic modular arithmetic, and we can invoke more abstract algebra. So equality is preferable in this more general and abstract context.